# android start a specific tab in a fragmentAcrivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have an activity that extends FragmentActivity, I use a custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter, a SlidingTabLayout and a pagerView.

In some cases I want my fragmentActivity to start on a specific (third, if it matters..) tab. 
I've tried lots of suggestion I found on SO but non worked. When I tries to use "pager.setCurrentItem(3)"  the problem was that onCreateView for that fragment was never called and therefore all objects and values are not assigned properly.

thanks for the help!

**EDIT**: Adding more info

this is how I init my adapter:

```
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, NewsTab.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PhotosTab.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AboutTab.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, NextTab.class.getName()));
    adapter =  new ProtestViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles, NumOfTabs, fragments);
```

this is my view pager adapter:

```
public class ProtestViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public final String TAG = "PRTST_V_PGR_ADPTR";
private CharSequence Titles[];
private int NumbOfTabs;
private List<Fragment> fragments;


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ProtestViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabs,
                               List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);

    this.fragments = fragments;
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabs;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
//        switch (position){
//            case 0:
//                NewsTab news  = new NewsTab();
//                return news;
//            case 1:
//                PhotosTab photos = new PhotosTab();
//                return photos;
//            case 2:
//                AboutTab about = new AboutTab();
//                return about;
//            case 3:
//                NextTab next = new NextTab();
//                return next;
//            default:
//                return null;
//        }
}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

each of the tabs implements FragmentInterface that only have

```
void fragmentBecameVisible();
```

and the "tabs" also extends "MyBaseTab" that extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: By any chance, is your pager right to left? Or does setting setcurrentitem works on other fragments?

Comment: not right to left, setcurrentitem only works on 0 as in setcurrentitem(0)